# process.waitFor() in android app returns "1"

Tags: android, process, runtime

I'm useing an exmaple i found for execute shell commands.([Link](http://madteam.co/news/2012/02/android-diy-making-a-shell-script-app/))

when i running the example it works prefectly,

but when i use the same code in my app it doesn't work because the return value is "1" instead of "0".
**This is where the problem begins :**

```
try 
{
proc.waitFor();
}
catch (InterruptedException e){}
```

The manifest.xml is the same and both apps are using jre1.6
i have searched for every difference but i didn't find any.

thanks.

Comment: Eventually it turn out to be a super-user settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you app whether it is signed one or unsigned one.
unsigned app doesn't have permission to assess Run time process.